# Can Tahoe-LAFS be used with FreeNAS (or OpenFiler) as a volume?

Tags: network-attached-storage, truenas, openfiler

Is it possible to somehow attach a Tahoe-LAFS volume in to FreeNAS (or OpenFiler) and use it as part of a FreeNAS volume group?